# CentOS-7 installation on two disks (SSD + HDD)

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, system-installation

I am trying to install CentOS-7(GNOME) on my Dell Laptop which has 30GB SSD and 1TB HDD, RAM of 8GB, i7 Intel processor.
I am doing manual partition.

I have selected SSD as bootable drive and my `/boot` is on SSD with 2GB as size.

In which drive should I put the leftover(28 GB) SSD  for better OS performance?

I tried adding it to `/` but this is only allowing me if I deselect HDD. But then I am not able to add other partitions like `/home`, `swap`, `/usr`, `/opt`, `/var` on HDD and they would all default to SSD which has only 30GB in total which I am trying to avoid.

I am planning to use this laptop for my development activities eg Java(with Intellij), Docker, Kubernetes, MongoDB, Apache Flink which at times would be resource consuming and I want to utilize SSD as much as feasible.

Does the CentOS installation always default to the disk with higher space?
Should I simply install to SSD(deselect HDD) and then after installation mount other partitions on HDD?

So far, I am trying to follow instructions [here](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/CustomSpoke-ppc64/#sect-custom-partitioning-ppc):

I'll appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on type of partitioning you want to use. With standard partitions you can select which disk will be used for which partition so you can place `/` on the SSD. This is unfortunately not possible with LVM -- LVM itself can do that with `lvcreate -L <size> -n <name> <vgname> /dev/sda` (assuming `sda` is your SSD) but this is not available in the installer GUI. So your options are:

1. Use *Standard Partition* partitioning scheme. After adding the `/` partition you can choose which disk it will be allocated on by clicking on *Modify* under *Devices* in the right column.[image]
2. Prepare the LVM setup manually before the installation and just select the pre-created LVs during the installation.

Note that 30 GB for `/` isn't that much and you might run out of space (but separate `/var` and `/opt` would help with that). Interesting option would be to use the SSD as [LVM cache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_cache_volume_creation) for the setup. But this option is again not available in GUI, you'd need to setup it manually or use kickstart where cache can be create using `logvol --cachesize <size> --cachepvs <pvs>` (see documentation [here](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#logvol))

Comment: The installation is only allowing /boot or /boot/efi to select SSD(sdb) if I use both the disk(SSD+HDD) i.e. "modify" of "/" throws error "container images impossible due to the devices it already contains" . If I deselect HDD then autoconfigure partition has no issues assigning all SSD to "/", "/boot", /"boot/efi","swap.